# django rest framework - return custom data for a model serializer field

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

I have the following model:

```
class ServerSimpleConfigSerializer(mixins.GetCSConfigMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mp_autoteambalance = serializers.BooleanField(label='Auto Team Balance', default=True, required=False)
    mp_friendlyfire = serializers.BooleanField(label='Friendly Fire', default=False, required=False)
    mp_autokick = serializers.BooleanField(label='Auto team-killer banning and idle client kicking', default=True, required=False)
    # hostname = serializers.CharField(label='Hostname', max_length=75, required=True)
    rcon_password = serializers.CharField(label='RCON Password', max_length=75, required=True)
    sv_password = serializers.CharField(label='Server Password', max_length=75, required=False)
    mp_startmoney = serializers.IntegerField(label='Start Money', required=False, validators=[MinValueValidator(800), MaxValueValidator(16000)])
    mp_roundtime = serializers.FloatField(label='Round Time', required=False)
    mp_timelimit = serializers.IntegerField(label='Map Time Limit', required=False)
    fpath = os.path.join(settings.ROOT_DIR, "cs16/tmp/server.json")

    class Meta:
        model = CS16Server
        fields = ('name', 'game_config', 'mp_autoteambalance', 'mp_friendlyfire',
                'mp_autokick', 'hostname', 'rcon_password', 'sv_password',
                'mp_startmoney', 'mp_roundtime', 'mp_timelimit')
        read_only_fields = ('name', 'game_config',)
```

The model has the following fields:

- name, game_config (big text) and hostname

How can I return the above defined fields for the serializer, although they are not present on the model ?

I would like to set some custom values for each field & return them as a JSON.
Is that possible ?
Actually the values for the above defined fields are found in "game_config" field.
I would like to parse those values & return them & I would not want to put them as separate fields in the model.

Parse game_config, obtain a pair of: (field0, val0) ... (fieldN, valN) and in the serializer,
set those values for the serializer fields.

For now I only get the following response:

```
{
    "name": "Chronos",
    "game_config": "hostname \"A New Gameservers.com Server is Born\"\nrcon_password \"\"\nsv_password \"1410271\"\nsv_contact email@domain.com\nsv_region 255\nsv_filterban 1\nsv_logbans 0\nsv_unlag 1\nmp_startmoney 800\nmp_chattime 30\nmp_footsteps 1\nsv_footsteps 1\nmp_logdetail 0\nmp_logmessages 0\nmp_timelimit 30\nmp_autokick 1\nmp_autoteambalance 1\nmp_flashlight 0\nmp_forcerespawn 0\nmp_forcechasecam 0\nmp_freezetime 0\nmp_friendlyfire 0\nmp_hostagepenalty 0\nmp_limitteams 0\nmp_roundtime 5\nmp_tkpunish 1\nsv_voiceenable 1\nsv_voicecodec voice_speex\nsv_voicequality 3\nsv_alltalk 0\nsv_restartround 1\nsv_maxspeed 320\nsv_proxies 1\nallow_spectators 1\nsv_allowupload 1\npausable 0\ndecalfrequency 40\nmp_falldamage 0\nsv_cheats 0\nsv_lan 0\nsv_maxrate 20000\nsv_minrate 4000\nexec listip.cfg",
    "mp_autoteambalance": true,
    "mp_friendlyfire": false,
    "mp_autokick": true,
    "hostname": "none"
}
```

Comment: You want use `ServerSimpleConfigSerializer ` for parse data from backend -> api, or you want use this serializer for save data? If you want only parse data -> api, with custom like anything you want, you can try `serializers.SerializerMethodField`

Comment: I want to use it to save data, but I also need to create some fields and return them based on the "game_config" field.

Comment: I can use the SerializerMehtodField, but I also want to be able to write data.
Hence, I need a way to compute data in order to return it, but I also need to write data using that field. SerializerMethodField is read-only.

Comment: Basically what I want is to be able to return "computed data" for those fields, but also have the posibility of writing data to those fields & then each value for each field would actually be put into "game_config" field.

So the fields of the serializer will not be written to a model, but those values would be put into "game_config" field, which exists in the model.

Comment: you can create one `serializers.SerializerMethodField ` for show data to api, and 1 normal field mapping database for save model. Like `game_config_data` is `SerializerMethodField` for return api, and `game_config` normal for `save` backend